# [Odoo][Qweb]Dictionary foreach, print key and value

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

Is there a way to print key and value from a python dictionary in loop **Qweb**?
For example, if I have a fuction that return a dictionary:

```
def get_informations(self):
    mydico={'myfirstkey':1,'mysecondkey':2}
    return mydico
```

And then, in Qweb report:

```
<t t-foreach="doc.get_informations()" t-as="l">
    <tr>
       <td class="text-right">
         <t t-esc="l"/>
       </td>
       <td class="text-right">
         <span t-esc="l_value"/>
       </td>
    </tr>
</t>
```

How could I print the **key** and the **value** ?

Thanks

*Update 07/12/15:*

Thank you for your return.
Exactly, when I put

```
 <t t-foreach="{'my': 'first', 'my2': 'second' }" t-as="v">
```

It works, I have something like:

```
my    first
my2   second
```

But when I use a function in *foreach*, with exactly the same output, qweb can't separate it, and I have:

```
{'my': 'first', 'my2': 'second' }
{'my': 'first', 'my2': 'second' }
```

So I decided to do another way:

In my inherit **report**:

```
<t t-foreach="doc.tabTaxes" t-as="v">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span t-esc="v.name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span t-esc="doc.get_amount(v.name)[0]"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</t>
```

In **sale.order** models inherit :

```
@api.one
def get_amount(self, taxeNom):
    total=0
    for ligne in self.order_line:
        for taxe in ligne.tax_id:
            if (taxeNom == taxe.name):
                try: total += ligne.price_reduce * (taxe.amount/100.)
                except: total +=0
    return "{0:.2f}".format(total)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I understood how to work with V9 :

```
<tr t-foreach="o.get_list_taxe(o.id)[0]" t-as="taxe">
  <t t-set="name" t-value="taxe['name']"/>
  <t t-set="total" t-value="taxe['total']"/>
  <td>
    <strong>
      <p>
        <t t-esc="name"/>
      </p>
    </strong>
  </td>
  <td class="text-right">
    <t t-esc="total" t-esc-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "res_company.currency_id"}'/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 12):

@FTK,

Given that your function is returning valid dictionary to qWeb template, the below code should do the job :

```
    <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure">
        <t t-foreach="{'my': 'first', 'my2': 'second' }" t-as="v">
         *<t t-esc="v"/> : <t t-esc="v_value"/></t>
    </div>
```

And you can put tr in loop so it will create table row as you expect, code below will do that way :

```
    <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <t t-foreach="doc.get_informations()" t-as="item">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <t t-esc="item"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <t t-esc="item_value"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </t>
        </table>
    </div>
```

you certainly don't need div their as required. 
Hope this will help you,

Bests,

Comment: Great answer, I didn't know about `*_value`!

Answer (score 3):

- **$as_all**

the object being iterated over

- **$as_value**

the current iteration value, identical to $as for lists and integers, but for mappings it provides the value (where $as provides the key)

> - Warning
>
> $as will be replaced by the name passed to t-as

Reference of this Link : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html

Comment: Hi @Jainik,
I trier to use that in V9, but didn't understand, could you give an example? For example : 

`<t t-foreach="doc._get_taxes()" t-as="item">
 <span t-value="item"/>
</t>`

Comment: The fact is that `doc._get_taxes()` returns a list, that's why I couldn't use it properly.
To do it, I wrote :

`<t t-set="tab" t-value="doc._get_taxes()[0]"/>
<t t-foreach="tab" t-as="index">
 <tr>
  <td class="text-right">
   <t t-esc="index"/>
  </td>
  <td class="text-right">
   <span t-esc="tab[index]"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</t>`

Comment: <span t-esc="index_value"/> this line give you a dict value.

Answer (score 3):

This was what worked for me because i discovered that as you iterate over a dictionary it returns a tuple containing two items `(key, value)`

```
<h4>Houses sold by type</h4>
  <t t-foreach="house_count" t-as="houses">
    <t t-set="house" t-value="houses[0]"/>
    <t t-set="count" t-value="houses[1]"/>
      <p><span t-esc="house" />: <span t-esc="count" /> houses sold</p>
  </t>
```

Just using houses as an example